# Ruby command line error

Tags: osx-mavericks

Hi I am new to all of this programming.  Trying to learn through the Odin Project.  They are having me do testing with the command 'rake' on my command line.  I have ruby version 2.1.2 installed and rspec installed too.  Anyway I get this error when trying to run the command 'rake'.

```
Joel-Prestons-MacBook-Air-4:00_hello joelpreston$ rake
(in /Users/joelpreston/learnRuby/learn_ruby)
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: can't activate rspec (~> 2), already activated rspec-3.0.0. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.
/Users/joelpreston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:262:in `block in replace_gem'
/Users/joelpreston/learnRuby/learn_ruby/Rakefile:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/joelpreston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/joelpreston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Joel-Prestons-MacBook-Air-4:00_hello joelpreston$
```

Can anyone please explain what I need to do to get rake to run?  Thanks in advance.  Joel

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I came across this solution,

install rspec version less than 3.0.0.

```
sudo gem install -v '< 3.0.0' rspec
```

I'm not sure this is the long term solution but it did work for me.

I found it on a post by Jayson Virissimo here:
[Rake aborted: could not find rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173433/rake-aborted-could-not-find-rspec)